# Проблемы с репутацией

Tags: дефект, репутация

До недавнего времени (один-дня два назад, точнее не засекал) у меня репутация была в районе 3.500. Сегодня утром прихожу, у меня репутация 3.997. Безусловно, я гений, но всё-таки хотелось бы узнать, откуда и за что накапало репутации? Или просто движок сбоит по-чёрному?

P.S. Сегодня капнуло +15 за принятый ответ, но это явно меньше, чем 400 единиц репутации.

Comment: То есть это пересчитанные по новой формуле плюсы за вопросы?